# Parse Facebook logInWithPermissions crash

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm developing an iOS app with Parse, and implementing Twitter and Facebook login.  My code is as follows;

```
var permissions = NSArray(array: ["user_about_me"])
    PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, {
    (user: PFUser!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if user == nil {
          NSLog("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
      } else if user.isNew {
          //Get data and fill in appropriate fields for PFUser
      } else {
          //login user
      }
    })
```

The problem is that when I click the button that runs this code, I get an error with the following text:

```
Error: Error Domain=PF_AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/html" UserInfo=0x79faa000 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Invalid OAuth Request, PF_AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7a174da0> { URL: https://api.parse.com/2/user_signup_or_login } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "*";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 21;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sat, 21 Feb 2015 20:12:11 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.0";
    "X-Parse-Platform" = G1;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.005746";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/user_signup_or_login, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/html, PF_AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7a165300> { URL: https://api.parse.com/2/user_signup_or_login }} (Code: 100, Version: 1.6.0)
2015-02-21 14:12:11.851 hotPotato[90663:4004200] Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.
```

It appears that something about my "permissions" array is not correct.  However, I think I've followed Parse's [instructions](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios) exactly save the fact that I am translating into swift.  Any ideas?

Comment: what version of the parse ios sdk are you using?

Comment: this is likely a bug in a specific version of the sdk you might be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in version 1.6.2 and below. Update your parse framework to 1.6.3 that was released on Jan 20th and it should clear up your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Error Domain=PF_AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/html"
```

The response you received has the content type text/html, but the error message says that it should be text/json, application/json or text/javascript. Add text/html to the accepted/allowed content types.